# How does there exist more than one face of the same person in Braavos, Game of Thrones?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In S05E10, Arya is about to be punished for killing the wrong person - Meryn Trant. As punishment, Jaqen H'ghar poisons himself and dies. When Arya is wailing over his dead body, the Waif beside her removes her mask and reveals herself to be Jaqen.

I understand the symbolism of identity in the show, and how many of Arya's trainers were simply using the identity of Jaqen, when in truth they are all no one. But physically, how does there exist two masks of Jaqen? Is it possible for a copy of a face to be made?

Later, when Arya keeps peeling off the masks off the dead Jaqen, there is also a mask of Arya shown (right before she goes blind). How did this happen as well? There is no indication during Season 5 that Arya's face was being duplicated. Did it happen offscreen?

Is there a better explanation to this in the books?

Comment: Meta note if you want to know from a book perspective you're better off asking over on scifi.stackexchange though I believe there's already a question asked about it there.

Comment: @Paulie_D The duplicate doesn't answer the question either :(

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Sorry, new to Stack Exchange, don't know how it works quite yet

Comment: @user61478 That's fine, this site is mainly for Movies and TV (hence the name) whereas SFF is for science fiction and fantasy whatever the format, hence the name. Like I said I'm 99% sure it's been asked over on SFF already though so I don't recommend posting it there unless you do some research there first otherwise it'll probably be dupe closed anyway. And welcome to the site/network!

Comment: I have to do research, but I think the idea is that as long as a face is not in use at "the exact same time", one could use it pretty quickly, put it back and another use it. The thing with this is though it seems like you can "layer" faces, as long as they are different. The only other answer if two people were using what appears to be the same face at the same time, is that perhaps there are identical twins that were killed??

Comment: I don't agree with the duplicate question being applicable here. The current question is not (only/mainly) about how they can appear to use Arya's face. The question here is (also) about the seeming contradiction that one needs a "face mask" to wear that face, but we see **two** people in quick succession who wear Jaqen's face, and they did not pass the "Jaqen face mask" to each other. That would suggest that you don't need to physically wear the "face mask" and instead can use any and all available faces at well, which is a valid and interesting question, and not answered by the duplicate.